# count minutes between str format "hh:mm - hh:mm" python

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime

I have pandas df with column TimeOfWork which has a type of str. All values there looks like this

"hh:mm - hh:mm"

I need new column with number of minutes each person worked. For example if there is a value "10:00 - 11:30" in column TimeOfWork there should be 90 in new column. People can work during midnight, so values can be "22:00 - 01:00"

Comment: It would be very convenient if there were some example dataframe code, with perhaps some attempts at what you've managed to do so far.

Comment: Would be helpful to [provide an MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including your df, what you have tried, and the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the TimeOfWork column to separate columns (startTime and endTime), parse those to datetime, calculate the timedelta and account for over-midnight hours. From the timedelta, you can easily get the total minutes worked. Ex:

```
import pandas as pd

# example data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'TimeOfWork': ["10:00 - 11:30",  "22:00 - 01:00"]})

# split to separate start and end of work columns
df[['startTime', 'endTime']] = df['TimeOfWork'].str.replace(' ', '').str.split('-', expand=True)

# parse to datetime and calculate timedelta
df['startTime'], df['endTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startTime'], format='%H:%M'), pd.to_datetime(df['endTime'], format='%H:%M')
df['deltaTime'] = df['endTime']-df['startTime']

# account for over-night hours (date change)
df.loc[df['deltaTime']<pd.Timedelta(0), 'deltaTime'] +=  pd.Timedelta(days=1)

# extract minutes
df['minutesWorked'] = df['deltaTime'].dt.total_seconds()/60

# df['minutesWorked']
# 0     90.0
# 1    180.0
# Name: minutesWorked, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` and convert the values `to_datetime`, take a difference between them, divide by `Timedelta(minutes=1)`, and fix the ranges spanning over the midnight by modulo dividing it by the number of minutes in one day (60*24):

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'TimeOfWork': ["10:00 - 11:30", "22:00 - 01:00"]})

# split the range and convert to datetime
z = df['TimeOfWork'].str.split(' - ', expand=True).apply(pd.to_datetime)

# calculate minutes worked
df['MinutesWorked'] = z[1].sub(z[0]).div(pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)) % (60*24)

df
```

Output:

```
      TimeOfWork  MinutesWorked
0  10:00 - 11:30           90.0
1  22:00 - 01:00          180.0
```